# R- Check if a new date range falls within an exisiting date range

Tags: r

I have a data table defined as below:

| Entity | Value | Sdate | EDate | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 1/1/2023 | 4/1/2023 | event1 |
| A | 6 | 6/1/2023 | 8/1/2023 | event2 |
| B | 8 | 1/1/2023 | 3/1/2023 | event1 |
| B | 9 | 5/1/2023 | 6/1/2023 | event2 |

If the user enters a new record with a date range for entity A as `A, 55, 2/1/2023, 2/20/2023`  (Feb 1st to Feb 20th), the code should not save this data to the database as the first entry of entity A already covers the entire date range from `Jan 1st to April 1st`..

How to check if the new SDate and EDate fall within the range of existing SDate and EDate in the dataframe for a particular entity

Comment: "If the user enters a new record", is there a user interface? How do users enter data? is there a database connection or just within R?

Comment: Good point. Yes, there is an interface. I build a dataframe based on the entered data. So, new data will be a single row dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `semi_join()` to figure out which rows should not be added, or an `anti_join()` to figure out which rows should be added. This requires dplyr 1.1.0.

I've added an extra "new" row that doesn't fall within any existing `"A"` range to show the difference.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- tibble(
  Entity = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  Value = c(5L, 6L, 8L, 9L),
  Sdate = as.Date(c("1/1/2023", "6/1/2023", "1/1/2023", "5/1/2023"), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
  Edate = as.Date(c("4/1/2023", "8/1/2023", "3/1/2023", "6/1/2023"), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
  Type = c("event1", "event2", "event1", "event2")
)
df
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   Entity Value Sdate      Edate      Type  
#>   <chr>  <int> <date>     <date>     <chr> 
#> 1 A          5 2023-01-01 2023-04-01 event1
#> 2 A          6 2023-06-01 2023-08-01 event2
#> 3 B          8 2023-01-01 2023-03-01 event1
#> 4 B          9 2023-05-01 2023-06-01 event2

new <- tibble(
  Entity = c("A", "A"),
  Value = c(55L, 56L),
  Sdate = as.Date(c("2/1/2023", "4/5/2023"), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
  Edate = as.Date(c("2/20/2023", "4/10/2023"), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
)
new
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   Entity Value Sdate      Edate     
#>   <chr>  <int> <date>     <date>    
#> 1 A         55 2023-02-01 2023-02-20
#> 2 A         56 2023-04-05 2023-04-10

# only the rows that SHOULD NOT be added
semi_join(new, df, by = join_by(Entity, within(Sdate, Edate, Sdate, Edate)))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>   Entity Value Sdate      Edate     
#>   <chr>  <int> <date>     <date>    
#> 1 A         55 2023-02-01 2023-02-20

# the rows that SHOULD be added
anti_join(new, df, by = join_by(Entity, within(Sdate, Edate, Sdate, Edate)))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>   Entity Value Sdate      Edate     
#>   <chr>  <int> <date>     <date>    
#> 1 A         56 2023-04-05 2023-04-10
```

Comment: How would it work in previous versions? I don't have privileges to update to the latest version of dplyr

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394743/davis-vaughan any alternate suggestions?

Comment: This feature didn't exist in previous dplyr versions, sorry